# Analyze memory with crash with kdump

Tags: linux, debugging, memory-leaks, crash-dumps

I have a kdump that says

```
crash> kmem -i
              PAGES        TOTAL      PERCENTAGE
 TOTAL MEM   468778       1.8 GB         ----
      FREE     2107       8.2 MB    0% of TOTAL MEM
      USED   466671       1.8 GB   99% of TOTAL MEM
    SHARED   193447     755.7 MB   41% of TOTAL MEM
   BUFFERS      746       2.9 MB    0% of TOTAL MEM
    CACHED   186315     727.8 MB   39% of TOTAL MEM
      SLAB    26366       103 MB    5% of TOTAL MEM

TOTAL SWAP   273103         1 GB         ----
 SWAP USED    27566     107.7 MB   10% of TOTAL SWAP
 SWAP FREE   245537     959.1 MB   89% of TOTAL SWAP
```

which doesn't look like a user space process memory leak.

How can I see with crash what is using the memory? I'm suspecting page cache overflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `ps` command from within the crash utility.