# How to analyze Kdump file in Ubuntu 12?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, coredump

I enabled Kdump and manually triggered a crash using this command:

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This created Kdump file with this name:

```
-rw------- 1 root whoopsie 285383602 Feb 16 07:17/var/crash/201802160716/dump.201802160716
```

How can I open the file for analysis? This is a binary file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analyze memory with crash with kdump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10421865/608639), [Analyzing CPU registers during kernel crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21850618/608639), [Core dump file analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis) and [How to analyze a program's core dump file with gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8305866/608639) Also see [How to use kdump to debug kernel crashes](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_kdump_to_debug_kernel_crashes) from Fedora.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core dump file analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis)

Comment: For me kdump analysis with crash utility work fine with SUSE and Red-Hat. First time, I am trying with ubuntu. I already tried with gdb to analyze gdb, but getting error as file format not recognized.

Comment: "/var/crash/201802160716/dump.201802160716": not in executable 


format: File format not recognized


(gdb)